# Cropping raster file with GDAL warp C++ API

Tags: gdal, clip, gdalwarp, c++, masking

I need to crop a DEM raster file with a shapefile. This shapefile has many polygons. I need to calculate several variables after the crop operation.

The algorithm is written in C++ so I want to call GDAL C++ API.
I do not need to write the warped file out to my disk and I intend to use either VRT or MEM once the test is passed.

I already obtain the coordinates of each polygon and I passed as a polygon using the cutline argument, but the operation has no effect so far.

```
            OGRLinearRing poExteriorRing;
            for (i = 0; i < nPt; i++) 
              {
                dX = (*iIterator).vVertex.at(i).dX;
                dY = (*iIterator).vVertex.at(i).dY;
                double dDummy1 = (dX - dX_origin) / dResolution_elevation;
                long lColumn_index = long(round(dDummy1));
                double dDummy2 = (dY_origin - dY) / dResolution_elevation;
                long lRow_index = long(round(dDummy2));     
                poExteriorRing.addPoint(lColumn_index, lRow_index);
              }
            poExteriorRing.closeRings();
            OGRPolygon polygon;
            polygon.addRing(&poExteriorRing);

            GDALDataset  *poVRTDS;
            poDS_elevation->GetGeoTransform(adfGeoTransform);
            poVRTDS = poDriver->CreateCopy( "./test.tiff", poDS_elevation, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL );

            GDALWarpOptions *psWarpOptions = GDALCreateWarpOptions();
            ...
            psWarpOptions->hCutline = &polygon;                
            GDALWarpOperation oOperation;
            oOperation.Initialize( psWarpOptions );
            oOperation.ChunkAndWarpImage( 0, 0,
                            GDALGetRasterXSize( poDS_elevation ),
                            GDALGetRasterYSize( poDS_elevation ) );
            GDALClose( poVRTDS );
```

I assume I need to construct the polygon vertex to image index according to:
CUTLINE: This may contain the WKT geometry for a cutline. It will be converted into a geometry by GDALWarpOperation::Initialize() and assigned to the GDALWarpOptions hCutline field. The coordinates must be expressed in source pixel/line coordinates. Note: this is different from the assumptions made for the -cutline option of the gdalwarp utility!
https://gdal.org/api/gdalwarp_cpp.html

Comment: What error messages are you getting? Which line is the error message being generated on?

Comment: The code does not give error. The the result tif is the same with the input, so the warp operation does not has effect.

Comment: Is your clip shape and raster input in the same coordinate reference system? If one is undefined or there isn't a geotransform you may see problems, though that scenario should trip a breakpoint.

Comment: My input files have the same map projection. This is the part I am not sure. The hCutline option is "Optional OGRPolygonH for a masking cutline", it is not a shapefile. But it can be defined from the shapefile. https://gdal.org/doxygen/structGDALWarpOptions.html#abf726bf4ef0927713370722ee34c6cc4

Comment: OGR_G_AssignSpatialReference(
        hMultiPolygon, OGR_L_GetSpatialRef(hLayer) );

    *phCutlineRet = hMultiPolygon;
It appears the spatial reference is required for the geometry object.

Comment: Yes, but according to https://gdal.org/api/gdalwarp_cpp.html#_CPPv415GDALWarpOptions the polygon must be in **cell units** not world units, you will need to subtract the origin and scale by cellsize as you prepare the WKT polyon, if that is true then there shouldn't be a spatial reference assigned to the polygon because it's no longer referenced to real world coordinates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112030/discussion-between-chang-and-michael-stimson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several attempts, I was able to fix the issues following some blog post: http://www.jeepxie.net/article/293437.html

The core part is that we need to convert coordinates:

```
eError = TransformCutlineToSource( hWrkSrcDS, hCutline,
                                  &(psWO->papszWarpOptions),
                                  psOptions->papszTO );
```

and we should not use both hCutline and cutline at the same time.